# Help me , i want to only call the id and need all the data like firstname,lastname,age etc in consol.log not like console.log(users.[0]); .

Tags: javascript, json

[ 
  {
    "id":1,
    "firstName":"Rahul",
    "lastName":"Kumar",
    "age":22,
    "gender":"Male",
    "qualification":"Btech",
    "mobileno":1234567891,
    "email":"r@xyz.com",
    "state":"Bihar"
  },

{
    "id":2,
    "firstName":"Ram",
    "lastName":"Kumar",
    "age":20,
    "gender":"Male",
    "qualification":"Btech",
    "mobileno":1234567892,
    "email":"ram@xyz.com",
    "state":"Assam"
  }
  ]

Comment: i dont want to call the array[0].

Comment: Please may you format your post, and include an intelligible question?

Comment: it's urgent kindly help

Comment: So edit the question. It's really hard to help if we don't understand the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
console.log(users.[0]);
```

returns the object at index 0. 
To access only the 'id' property of the objec, do:

```
console.log(users[0].id);
```

Comment: sorry to confuse you,

Comment: my question is i am calling only id = 1 and in result i get all the data in it.console.log(users.[0]) // call in array . console.log(user[0].id)// for calling only value of id.

Comment: in SQL we write ( select * from table1 where id = 1) // shows all the data in id = 1. same result i want in console.log when i call id.